# Deleting the ActiveX textbox and command buttons without using VBA i.e directly from sheet

Tags: vba, activex

I am not able to understand the working of activex controls:

1) I inserted a text box and command box on my worksheet 
2) I double-clicked on them and the VBA editor opens 
3) I typed some code and ran it

> > Now, when I go back to the worksheet and try to delete any of those, I am not able to. Because right-click on those boxes is not working and left-click only runs the program.

Please help

Comment: Have you tried the Edit-Mode in Developer Tools? With this on you should be able to just left click on these